# QR code scanning issue zxing iOS 6.0.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, qr-code, iphone-5

i am working on an application where we need to scan QR codes for iPhone.
I am using zxing API for it. App is working great with iOS 6.0.1 but it's not working right with the latest release of iOS 6.0.2.

I am sending the scanned QR code to the server which gives me this response. 
For example, if the QR code is 00012123456789000134,
iOS 6.0.1 version is giving me 00012123456789000134 as result but iOS 6.0.2 gives the result as 2100012123456789000134\u001D0111223344556677. 
I don't know what is the problem. Is it due to the fixes in iOS 6.0.2 ????
Please help me out.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to scan with ZXing's own scan app from the app store, you need to check that out first to make sure that the problem is not the SDK nor the QR Code you are scanning.

If it is related to your code, review how you the result string is handled and moved to the output. it can be any of a few things, Zombies, incompatible types and moving between them, but mostly logic error. If you can post your codes, a lot more people will probably be able to help you.  Also always the thing that ultimately helps is a lot of printfs.